# Spec Explorer - New states being added when should loop

Tags: specifications, explorer, state-machine

I've been using Spec Explorer for about a month now on a big project,
it´s been going well besides one thing
Sometimes new states are being generated instead of looping, for example
- Create object, new state
- Do something with object, new state
- Do something that changes nothing (trying to create same object, does not change any state variables) here I get a new state instead of looping

Most of the times it loops, like it should, sometimes not, and there is absolutely no difference in the state comparison view except for the two top lines that only covers the description as to how the state came to be.

Anyone had similar problems or knows what´s going on?

Comment: You need to included a MCVE

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons. 
But in most cases the problem is: scenarios introduce control states.
Here the deepest explanation you can get on "How are identical states identified?"

"Ideally, we would identify two states when they

(a) have the same state contents, and

(b) have the same future behavior.

The reason why (a) is not enough is that enabled actions don’t depend on the state contents only, but also potentially on scenarios applied in a Cord script. Scenarios introduce control states.

The problem here is that checking (b) is not feasible in practice, as it would imply looking ahead all paths stemming from a state.

So we rely on a heuristic, consisting on identifying states that not only have the same contents, but are also produced in the same step of a scenario. 
So two states are equivalent if they contain the same data AND can perform the same actions.

For example, in a scenario such as A; A; B*, we have three states, all with the same (empty) contents.

When we compose this scenario in parallel with a model program, states corresponding to these three states will not be merged, regardless of their contents.

As a consequence, when you are comparing two states to understand why they are not merged, you should not just look at the values of their variables (data state), but also at the state description, which provides the control state.

States which have been generated by different machines using Spec Explorer heuristic cannot safely considered by a single state. 
As said, this is just a safe heuristic. So there’s no guarantee that two conceptually-equivalent states will always be merged; 
but two states that are not conceptually equivalent should never be merged."